# Cannot change Feign Default client. PATCH mapping does not work

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, spring-cloud-feign, feign

Config file

```
@Configuration
public class MyApiConfig {
    @Bean
    Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.FULL;
    }

    @Bean
    public OkHttpClient client() {
        return new OkHttpClient();
    }
}
```

Client class

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "wallesterApi",
    url = "https://api-frontend.wallester.com/v1",
    primary = false,
    configuration = [MyApiConfig::class]
)
interface WallesterApi {

    @RequestMapping(value = ["/cards/{card_id}/replace"], method = [RequestMethod.PATCH])
    fun replaceCard(
        @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") authorization: String,
        @PathVariable(name = "card_id") cardId: String
    ): WallesterCardResponse
}
```

application config with feign

```
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        logger-level: full
  okhttp:
    enabled: true
```

I have also dependencies

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
            <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId> <!-- Required to use PATCH -->
        </dependency>
```

Spring boot 2.7.3,
Spring Cloud 2021.0.8

My HTTP PATCH requests fail with `<--- ERROR ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method: PATCH (4ms)`

---

I tried guides that exist here, also tried `http-client` instead of `okhttp`

What I can see is that noting actually influences `FeignAutoConfiguration` class. I can't event get there with debug breakpoints. I still get default http client without PATCH support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason - **adding dependencies** or changing **application.yml** - was **not** a solution for me.

I tried many different configurations and advices.
I came to a custom solution, with overriding `feign client configuration` and client manually.

I linked code that works for me in a simple example in GitHub
https://github.com/vadimyemelyanov/feignpatchfix

Hope that will help somebody ^)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `FeignAutoConfiguration`, it can make use of `ApacheHttp5Client` if it's detected on the classpath. The issue is that `feign-httpclient` provides a class named `ApacheHttpClient`, so auto configuration cannot really detect it.

To resolve the issue, you can provide a `feign-hc5` dependency that introduces `ApacheHttp5Client` which will be automatically picked up by Feign auto configuration:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
    <artifactId>feign-hc5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```